# EJB and managed bean injections in @FacesConverter and @FacesValidator in JSF 2.3

Tags: jsf, converters, jsf-2.3

`@FacesConverter` and `@FacesValidator` are not eligible for EJB or managed bean injection points up to JSF 2.2.

They are supposed to work with JSF 2.3 (currently available as a [milestone](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.0-m02/) only) using an additional `managed` attribute with `@FacesConverter` and `@FacesValidator` as mentioned [here](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-23/#1316b).

> In JSF 2.1 very few JSF artifacts were injection targets. In JSF 2.2
>   injection was made possible in a huge amount of additional artefacts
>   but the very ones where injection actually matters most, **converters
>   and validators, were mysteriously left in the cold**.
>
> In JSF 2.3 this has now finally been taken care of as the following
>   artefacts have been added to the list of injection targets:
>
> - `javax.faces.convert.Converter`
> - `javax.faces.validator.Validator`
> - `javax.faces.component.behavior.Behavior`
>
> However, in contrast to the artefacts already on this list these new 3
>   are not automatically injection targets. **They will only become so
>   when a new attribute called "managed" on the corresponding annotations
>   `@FacesConverter`, `@FacesValidator` and `@Behavior` is set to true.**
>   Furthermore all these 3 annotations have been upgraded to being CDI
>   qualifiers by adding the `@Qualified` annotation to their definition.
>
> The existing attributes of `@FacesConverter`, `@FacesValidator` and
>   `@Behavior` have not been modified, meaning they are all *binding*, as
>   is the new attribute "managed".

The attribute `managed` is however, unavailable in Mojarra 2.3.0-m02.

Is it because of a milestone? Is it dependent upon a specific Weld/CDI version? I am currently going with GlassFish Server 4.1. Different artifact versions are mentioned [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/spotlight_on_glassfish_4_16) (The default Weld version supplied by the server version is 2.2.2 final).

Comment: Just tried on Tomcat 8.0.21 + Weld 2.2.10 + Mojarra 2.3.0-m02 and I can see that it failed when `faces-config.xml` is still declared conform JSF 2.2. After I updated it to JSF 2.3, it works. Is your `faces-config.xml` declared conform JSF 2.3? I.e. `/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd` and `version="2.3"` respectively (if the IDE errors on the XSD being unavailable, just ignore it).

Comment: With `/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd` and `version="2.3"`, the browser shows  500 (Internal Server Error). This is [untraceable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27795529/1391249) in my real app. This however, works in a project with a single XHTML file where the IDE also shows `@FacesConverter(managed = false)` and `@FacesValidator(managed = false)` as default which in the real app is however, a compile-time error - `cannot find symbol  symbol:   method managed()  location: @interface FacesValidator`.

Comment: I posted an answer. As to your "real app", I suspect classpath pollution with an older versioned JSF API (not impl), perhaps via something like `javaee.jar`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in Mojarra 2.3.0-m02's [`Application#createConverter()` implementation](https://github.com/omnifaces/mojarra/blob/b845e5d08549927b323ebdcca36bc7b01341db8e/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/application/ApplicationImpl.java#L1349), it [checks if it's running in JSF 2.3 mode](https://github.com/omnifaces/mojarra/blob/b845e5d08549927b323ebdcca36bc7b01341db8e/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/application/ApplicationImpl.java#L2635) as per `faces-config.xml` `version` declaration before trying to grab a CDI-managed one.

In other words, in order to get `@FacesConverter(managed=true)`, `@FacesValidator(managed=true)` and thus `@Inject` in those classes to work, you need to make sure that your webapp's `faces-config.xml` is declared conform JSF 2.3 as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</faces-config>
```

Noted should be that the IDE may error on the [JSF 2.3 XSD](http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd) file not being publicly available (yet), you can safely ignore that part, it won't be validated during runtime by JSF. You could alternatively stick to 2.2 XSD and ignore any IDE warning/error on an unsupported `version`.

---

The jdevelopment.nl blog author has been notified about this and he will make sure that in a next update the above is clarified in blog as well.

Comment: The IDE (NetBeans 8.0.2) also does not issue any error in a playground project. Therefore, the problem with the real application is a story apart and it is something to dig further in. Thank you.

Comment: Small side-note: Don't forget the `web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd` part to be upgraded to `web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd` as well. :-) Meanwhile, you can do "manual" lookup by using `CDI.current().select(SomeBackingBean.class).get()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798529/how-to-programmatically-inject-a-java-cdi-managed-bean-into-a-local-variable-in